# .net core windows service to enable Https

Tags: .net, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-codes

I have .net core 3.1 project where we have implemented some API with swagger UI. And we are using this app as windows service with http 5000 port. Now I have to enable https on this windows service.

Currently it's working fine with http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html
But now I wanted to enable https on this windows service.

Can please anybody help..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to use HTTPS for the local development site and visit https://localhost or https://mysite.example (custom hostname), you need a TLS certificate. But the browser does not consider any certificate to be valid: your certificate needs to be signed by an entity that your browser trusts, called a trusted certification authority (CA). You can refer to this article:https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/